# How can I get my img src to keep changing between 3-4 images when hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, src

I am currently working on a college project for a clothing website, so what I want is that when the user hovers over a product image on the main feed, the product image keeps changing between 3-4 images of that product with a few milliseconds of transition.

this is my HTML code

```
<div class="imagebox">
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/Mom Sarees/5pcs/A93A5321.JPG" alt="Saree no: A93A5321 "></a>
            </div>
```

this is the CSS

```
.imagebox{
display: inline-block;}

.imagebox img{
margin-top: 20px;
height: 400px;
margin-right: 10px;}
```

Is there a way to do that using CSS or JS?

Comment: Do you want them to fade in and out or just appear/disappear? Have you tried a CSS animation for example?

Comment: @AHaworth Primary need is to get the images to change from one to two to three to four to one, like this. 
fade-in/fade-out will obviously look nicer, but first I want to know how to get the img srcs to change

Comment: Several ways. A simple one would be to have all 4 images there one above the other (position absolute) and animate the opacity using keyframes see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: @AHaworth Haworth yes, that seems like a good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented an example by JS, I hope this will be helpful.

```js
let intervalId;
let i = 0;

document.querySelectorAll('.product-images').forEach((poroduct) => {
  const productImages = poroduct.querySelectorAll('img');

  poroduct.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    fadeImg(productImages);
    intervalId = setInterval(() => fadeImg(productImages), 1500);
  });

  poroduct.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    productImages[i].classList.remove('active');
    productImages[0].classList.add('active');
    i = 0;
  });
});

function fadeImg(productImages) {
  productImages[i].classList.remove('active');
  i = (i + 1) % 4;
  productImages[i].classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.imagebox {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 15px;
}

.imagebox img {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.imagebox img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="product-images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/550000/?text=Image1" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/005500/?text=Image2" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000055/?text=Image3" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/005555/?text=Image4" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="product-images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000000/?text=Image1" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/faaa22/?text=Image2" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/885500/?text=Image3" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/f500aa/?text=Image4" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="product-images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/0000ff/?text=Image1" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/00ff00/?text=Image2" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/?text=Image3" />
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ffff00/?text=Image4" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that, when I do "position: absolute", to .imagebox img, all the images come to the same place because I have multiple .image box div, inside each .imagebox I have a product image, so there are multiple .imagebox div. containing images of that product.

Comment: It's depend on your css styles to put products next to each other, I've edited my answer so that there are 3 boxes and every box has own images. pleas check it out. Thank you.

Comment: I used the same css as you did and it worked, thank you, but still, a problem lies, I have 10+ products let's say, I want them to go on to the next line when they don't fit in the same row anymore without their sizes getting affected, but since am using the position:absolute property, I can't use flex-wrap:wrap, therefore the more products I add more the images sizes of the products gets reduced to fit them in the same row.

Comment: It's not related to the position absolute of images, your issue is related to `.imagebox` , you can lie your grid with dynamic or fix width and set images width `100%`. position absolute is just for place images on the each other like a stack.